# vectorising a for loop in Matlab with if checks inside the loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, vectorization

This is a Matlab code:

```
new=[];
for i=1:size(p,1)
    if (alpha*p(i,1)+beta*p(i,2)+gamma*p(i,3)-sigma)>0
    new=[new;p(i,:)];
    end
end
```

Here `p` is a large array of size like 300000x3. The `new` array is obtained by deleting some 3-tuples from the `p` array. For this a `if` check is done. But this takes a lot of time.

I wish to vectorise the code like obtain a binary array with 1 for points retained and 0 for points deleted. Then using these flags, we can construct the `new` array more quickly. Am i right? Can someone give the code for vectorising or speeding the above code?

Comment: _"Can someone give the code for vectorising or speeding the above code?"_. Sorry this is not how it works on SO. Next time you write a question, try to vectorize this by yourself first and provide your efforts. There is also a good chance that you would have managed to do this by yourself and learn something as a positive side effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
selectRows = (alpha*p(:,1)+beta*p(:,2)+gamma*p(:,3)-sigma)>0;
new = p(selectRows, :);
```